# EXE stops working after compile. (Mysql C++ Connector)

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks, mysql-connector

Im using `Code::Blocks 13.12` with `MingW 4.8.1` on Windows 8.
I tried to link the `MySQL C++ Connector 1.1.4` in dynamic and static way.
When compiling it doesn't give error, but when starting exe it stops working.

I tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "cppconn/driver.h"

using namespace sql;

int main() {
    Driver *driver;
    Connection * con;
    std::cout << "1\n";
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    std::cout << "2\n";
    con = driver->connect("TCP://127.0.0.1:3306", "test", "test");
    std::cout << "3\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Building doesn't give error:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in mysql_connect (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -fexceptions -g -DCPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC= -ID:\Development\Libraries\boost_1_56_0 -c D:\Development\Projects\codeblocks\mysql_connect\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LD:\Development\Libraries\boost_1_56_0 -o bin\Debug\mysql_connect.exe obj\Debug\main.o   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\lib\opt\mysqlcppconn.lib"
Output file is bin\Debug\mysql_connect.exe with size 66.01 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

Here is the log given by `gdb`:

```
Starting debugger: D:\Development\Compiler\MingW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args              D:/Development/Projects/codeblocks/mysql_connect/bin/Debug/mysql_connect.exe
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Child process PID: 4236
In RaiseException () (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll)
#13 0x00401468 in _fu1___ZSt4cout () at D:\Development\Projects\codeblocks\mysql_connect\main.cpp:13
D:\Development\Projects\codeblocks\mysql_connect\main.cpp:13:252:beg:0x401468
At D:\Development\Projects\codeblocks\mysql_connect\main.cpp:13
Continuing...
[Inferior 1 (process 4236) exited with code 0377]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

`1` and `2` are printed successfully on the console, but `3` is not. `Process returned 255 (0xFF)`.

The program fails at this line:

```
con = driver->connect("TCP://127.0.0.1:3306", "test", "test");
```

Could anyone help to get it work?

Comment: If i comment the connection line it works. Prints 1,2,3.

Comment: Does your firewall allow outgoing connections for this exe?

Comment: Yes! The problem caused by `Code::Blocks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! The problem was my IDE. It seems the `MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.4` **only** works with `Microsoft Visual C++ 2003` or above.

If you have same issue just install `Microsoft Visual C++ 2003` or newer and link the library properly.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

```
con = driver->connect("TCP:://127.0.0.1:3306", "test", "test");
```

you have above one and MySQL website has below code.

```
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
```

I don't see much difference. Are you sure the username,password and the port the same as you mentioned in you code?

Comment: Yes im sure! I can connect to it from anywhere else.